# Develop Results View Page in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

This is probably going to be quite an easy question for everyone, and I have tried following and understanding tutorials, but I just cant get my head around it!!

Ok so for University me and my peers are creating a student assesment system, my task is to create a results view page.

Basically I have been given a file called index.php which has a template background with a header and footer thats just looks like a normal web page. I need to be able to display results from a table from a database (I dont have yet but can create a test to test it) that has data into a certain position of that index.php page.

I have phpadmin installed and have tried creating a test database and table to insert in, but it just doesnt work when i follow tutorials like this one http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/php-mysql/display_table_data.htm , i just cant understand it, which im sure if my fault!!!

Someone else is writing the query's ill need, but firstly im just trying to understand how I even do this, and how i tell it to go to the index.php page, and where to place the table on that page.

This is the php code for the index.php file if i open it in notepad ++

```
<?php
/*use template to create pages*/
include('templates/header.html');
include('templates/topMenu.html');
?>


<div id="contentwrap"> 

<div id="content">

<div style="clear: both;"> </div>
</div>

<?php
require_once('templates/sidebarStudent.php');
?>

<div style="clear: both;"> </div>

</div>

<?php
include('templates/footer.html'); 
?>
```

So my question is do I just enter some code somewhere in this index.php file that tells it where to get the database and table from? and how do I tell it where to position the table in the page, or do I have to create seperate php files for this?

Please help! :(

Answer (score 0):

If you were able to create some sort of test database, then you can use this basic code example to get up and running. You can put this inside one of those <div> tags to get the content to show up where you need it. Make sure you update the parameters below for your database username, password, database name, etc.

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'db_user_name_here', 'db_password_here');
mysql_select_db('db_name_here', $link);

$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM table_name_here');

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['column_name_here'] . "<br>";
}

mysql_close($link);

?>
```

If you still have trouble, then you'll need to make sure you have a proper database user, a database, and a table inside that database. It might be best to look for a tutorial because it will likely walk you through the steps necessary better than I can do here.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent question.
It rarely occurs when someone even bother with it.
Most of time the usual scenario for the PHP script is just to put everything into one perfect mess.

Yes, you have to always use separate files for the PHP and HTML code (*business and presentation logic* to be correct).

The guy who is writing queries have to put all the code into separate file which collects all the data into some variables which have to be passed into template file.
Then his code has to set the name of the file which contains the page template.
And finally call your main page template.

So, the index.php file should contain NO HTML code, but PHP only:

```
<?
//include settings, connect to database etc.
include dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']).'/cfg/settings.php';
//getting required data
$DATA = db::getarr("SELECT * FROM links");
// setting title for using in the main template
$pagetitle = "Links to friend sites";
//etc
//set page template filename
$tpl = "links.tpl.php";
//and then finally call a template:
include "main.tpl.php";
?>
```

where `main.tpl.php` is your main site template, including common parts, like header, footer, menu etc (there is no need to have header and footer in the separate files):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>My site. <?=$pagetitle?></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="page">
<? include $tpl ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and `links.tpl.php` is the actual page template:

```
<h2><?=$pagetitle?></h2>
<ul>
<? foreach($DATA as $row): ?>
<li><a href="<?=$row['link']?>" target="_blank"><?=$row['name']?></a></li>
<? endforeach ?>
<ul>
```

Eventually you may come to more complex designs, like with front controller one, but for the first site this one is both easy and powerful.